# Is there a word for "hard camping"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

You can say "go camping", meaning light trip outdoors, more like a picnic. By what about serious trips across tundra or some uninhabited land, with a heavy backpack?

In short, is there a word for "hard trip outdoors"?

Comment: You might want to ask on [our Great Outdoors Stack Exchange site](outdoors.stackexchange.com) - they would know first hand. Also I wouldn't ever consider going on a picnic to be camping. You will find varied definitions of this by region and experience, it isn't universal.

Comment: I have to agree, camping implies that you will be setting up camp. As in you're going to be spending at least a night out.
A picnic hardly counts.

Comment: Picnics definitely do not qualify as camping.

Answer (score 12):

> Expedition
>
> Trek
>
> Adventure

All of these words are applicable to a difficult trip.

Comment: I'm much more in favor of the first two than the third option. "Adventure" isn't wrong, but it could be used to describe a day at an amusement park just as easily as it could refer to heavy-duty hiking.

Comment: @JR They all require the camping context. An expedition or trek could just as easily be a drive from NY to LA.

Answer (score 10):

Back-woods camping

roughing it

If the trip is indeed a back packing trip, then backpacking is a good word.

Perhaps "wilderness camping"

Comment: +1 for "roughing it"; that has the "serious effort, no-frills" sense (no car, no pre-made campsites, nothing that you don't pack in (and out again), etc.)

Answer (score 6):

"backpacking" is probably the right word here - your context seems to imply carrying all your living supplies and setting up camp in places other than designated campgrounds.

Comment: _Backpacking_ is also used by people that indeed put all their stuff in a backpack, but travel from hostel to hostel, while the greatest physical challenge they are likely to encounter during their trip is (over)consumption of alcohol.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, always thought of backpacking as of "unofficial travelers". But it's still mostly about travelling throught cities and civilization. I am talking more about outdoor/countryside trips.

Comment: When I first went hiking with a backpack (20+miles per day, for two weeks), I called it backpacking. That is long ago. Now, when you mention backpacking, people (at least around where I am) associate it with youngsters trying to get as much fun, sun and drinks for as little money as possible :)

Comment: This discussion shows that this word – like so many others – can mean different things to different audiences. That's just the way English works.

Comment: @J.R. As does any other language.

Comment: I've been backpacking all throughout the USA, and everybody I've ever gone with has called it backpacking.  Try to do a Google search for "expedition magazine" or "adventure magazine."  Now try "backpacker magazine."  Bingo.  Not sure about worldwide, but in USA this is definitely the best answer.  Trekking might be a distant second but still nothing I ever hear used in real conversation.

Comment: Google images: https://www.google.com/search?q=backpacking&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch Though I myself to say "I want backpacking in those and those mountains/that and that national park", so that does take care of the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

"Backcountry" camping is what I would use to describe remote or hike-to camping. It's also the terminology used by the U.S. National Park Service to describe their hike-to, "backcountry campsites". It doesn't suffer the same ambiguity as "backpacking," which could also describe almost any kind of traveling where you carry everything in a backpack.

Answer (score 1):

This is often known as [*Yomping*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+yomp&oq=define+yomp).

This term is used for an arduous journey on foot across wild territory.
The word was originally a slang term from the British Royal Marines but came into wider use in the 1980s as the Marines famously yomped across the Falkland Islands.

Comment: Interesting. I think this might be a BrE word. I don't recall hearing it before today. (I hope you don't mind me adding a link, so the curious can go learn more.)

Answer (score 1):

Backcountry or wilderness camping are the terms used by the National Parks Service in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Bivouac might be what you're looking for. It generally involves little to no cover, so it might be a terrible idea in the Tundra!